# Display percentages in file name

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to save the name of my file(s) partially based on cell values in one of my sheets. I have the following code:

```
Sheets("Input").Range("F18").Value & " - " & Sheets("Input").Range("M13").Value
```

The problem is I want the title to display as a percentage and not a value, or some cases as a dollar amount and not a value. Can someone explain how do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will save a file with a name such as "Filename-50%-$23.xlsx"

For now i am assuming the following (please comment and inform me if I am wrong)

- You want to save a file you have open (word doc or excel sheet?)
- You want to name that file based on the values in F18 and M13
- The values can be either percentages or a cost in dollars
- F18 will always be a percentage and M13 will always be in dollars
- Values entered into cells are just the numerical value and the cells have been formatted to % or currency.

(It will help if in the future you lay your problem out a bit more obviously and include what you have tried so far)

```
    Sub testSave()

Dim SaveToDirectory As String

 'just checking string looks good comment or delete when happy
MsgBox ("other text you want " & Cells(18, 6).Value * 100 & "%-$" & Format(Cells(13, 13).Value, "#,###.##"))

    'set save directory
    SaveToDirectory = "C:\Users\DMASON2\Documents\"

    'set file name
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=SaveToDirectory & "FileName-" & Cells(18, 6).Value * 100 & "%-$" & Format(Cells(13, 13).Value, "#,#*.##"), FileFormat:=xlWorkbookDefault


    End Sub
```

Now to explain what i did.

Firstly when you format a cell to percentage value and enter in 0.5 excel will change it to 50% automatically however the cell value is still 0.5 so when you access it you just need to do the same process excel does to display a basic number as a percentage.

1. multiple by 100 (0.5 becomes 50)
2. Add in the percentage char after the number

   ```
   Sheets("Input").Cells(Row, Column).value * 100 & "%"
   ```

Now the currency is simpler as the value that you see doesn not change, all you need to do is add in the currency Char

```
   "$" & Sheets("Input").Cells(row, column).value
```

Now for saving the document. As i has no idea what sort of document you wished to save i just used saving the active one as an example. The filename is a combination of the location (saveToDirectory) and the actual filename we constructed above. Note i have just called it "filename" (you can change this to a variable string or anything you want). Finaly for excel docs you have a number of different options whens saving a workboot, i chose to use the users default type. [See file types for saving excel docs here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff198017%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

```
  ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=SaveToDirectory & "FileName-" & Cells(18, 6).Value * 100 & "%-$" & Cells(13, 13).Value, FileFormat:=xlWorkbookDefault
```

**UPDATE**

I found a very simple way to include commas in the currency numbers using Format

```
      Format(value, #,###.##)
```

or

```
      Format(value, "Standard")
```

or (you can omit the $ sign from the string if you use this version)

```
      Format(value, "Currency")
```

This method can also be used for the Percent values (again you can omit the % sign in string with this method)

```
      Format(Value, "Percent")
```

[Information on Format function](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/format_string.php)
See

Comment: How would you go about adding commas if the value is 1000 or more?

Comment: I honestly don't know. I will have a look and see what i can find though so bare with me. In the mean time if your values in those cells are not always currency in one and % in the other you could use this to check what format they are. `ActiveSheet.Cells(Row,Column).NumberFormat` [link to info](http://www.globaliconnect.com/excel/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=121:custom-number-formats-date-a-time-formats-in-excel-a-vba-numberformat-property&catid=79&Itemid=475)

Comment: On a different post a person mention that you can use a "," within a file name so I suppose it may not even be possible.

Comment: [these are the naming rules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx) so it is possible (I also just gave it a go saving a word file with a "," in). Not actually had a chance to think about it but maybe try searching for int to string with formatting? (and let me know if you find an answer)

Comment: So strange. I had a button i created within Design Mode to run the macro. My ultimate problem wasn't what was coded, but that the code linked to the button wasn't updating when i change the code on my macro. Once modified the code by Viewing Code through design mode i was fine!. I used ".Text" to get the commas to show up and " - $" for the dollar sign.