# Formatting file name as currency

Tags: excel, vba

Can you explain why this code does not include a $ when saving as a file name?

```
Sheets("Input").Range("F18").Value & " - $" & Sheets("Input").Range("M13").Value
```

When I run the file to pdf it simply disregards the $. How can I change the cell value M13 to be formatted as a dollar amount, preferably including "," when at or over $1,000

Thanks!

Comment: It might be interpreted as a special character. Try `$$` instead of just '$'. Does that work?

Answer (score 0):

You can't include a `,` in your file name! So you can't carry that format in to the filename in any way. However, if your just talking about the cell when looking on the sheet, right click and format it that way in the options

As for the "$" not showing, try this:

```
Dim FName as string
Fname = Sheets("Input").Range("F18").Value & " - $" & Sheets("Input").Range("M13").Value
```

Works fine when tested.

**Update**

Tested again with this:

```
Sub test()

Dim N1 As Double

N1 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B3")

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ("Test - $" & N1)


End Sub
```

where N1 = 1000 formated as $X,XXX.xx (where x is a number obviously) and works fine. The output I got was a file name called: *Test - $1000.xls*

Comment: Oh I forget you can't use a ",". But the $ is not working for me for some reason

Comment: @user1813558 see revised answer

Comment: @Liam Bee I have recently tried this and i was able to save a file with a comma in it with no problem... See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24056206/display-percentages-in-file-name/24059467?noredirect=1#comment37114103_24059467). the comma doesn't appear to be in the invalid saving characters

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub testSave()

Dim SaveToDirectory As String

'just checking string looks good comment or delete when happy
MsgBox ("other text you want " & Cells(18, 6).Value * 100 & "%-" & Format(Cells(13, 13).Value, "Currency"))

'set save directory
SaveToDirectory = "C:\Users\DMASON2\Documents\"

'set file name
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=SaveToDirectory & "FileName-" & Cells(18, 6).Value * 100 & "%-" & Format(Cells(13, 13).Value, "Currency"), FileFormat:=xlWorkbookDefault


End Sub
```